# TypeVar describing a class that must subclass more than one class

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I would like to create a type annotation `T` that describes a type that must be a subclass of both class `A` and class `B`.

`T = TypeVar('T', bound=A)` only specifies that `T` must be a subclass of `A`.

`T = TypeVar('T', A, B)` only specifies that `T` must be a subclass of `A` or a subclass of `B` but **not necessarily both.**

I actually want something like `T = TypeVar('T', bound=[A, B])` which would mean `T` must subclass both `A` and `B`. Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is an *intersection type*. Strictly speaking, I do not believe Python's type annotations support this (at least not yet). However, you can get something similar with a `Protocol`:

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

class A:
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 42
class B:
    def bar(self) -> bool:
        return False

class C(A, B): pass
class D(A): pass
class E(B): pass

class ABProtocol(Protocol):
    def foo(self) -> int: ...
    def bar(self) -> bool: ...

T = TypeVar('T', bound=ABProtocol)

def frobnicate(obj: T) -> int:
    if obj.bar():
        return obj.foo()
    return 0

frobnicate(C())
frobnicate(D())
frobnicate(E())
```

Mypy complains:

```
test.py:26: error: Value of type variable "T" of "frobnicate" cannot be "D"
test.py:27: error: Value of type variable "T" of "frobnicate" cannot be "E"
```

Of course, this requires you to explicitly annotate all the methods yourself, unfortunately, something like `class ABProtocol(A, B, Protocol): pass` isn't allowed

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on Protocols. I think this is actually good enough for my use case since I only care about one or two methods from each parent class.