# How to type hint generic multiple inheritance for factory methods

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-typing, pylance

I have a function that accepts two classes and creates a subclass that inherits from both. I want to hint that the output is a subclass of the two parent classes. For example, something like this.

```py
from typing import NewType, TypeVar

A = TypeVar("A")
B = TypeVar("B")
# A class that will inherit from A and B
C = NewType("C", (A, B,))

def class_factory(a: type[A], b: type[B]) -> type[C]:
    # Creates the class
    ...
```

The VS Code syntax highlighter is not picking up that the output of `class_factory` has all of the attributes and methods of `A` and `B`. Is this a limitation of the syntax highlighter, or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeVar describing a class that must subclass more than one class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785679/typevar-describing-a-class-that-must-subclass-more-than-one-class)

Comment: Even without the TypeVars, there's currently no way to represent "intersection types".  Also, `C = NewType("C", (A, B,))`  is a type error

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The big thing is it has to be generic, so implementing a protocol doesn't work. I found a workaround, but it's a bit weird. Will edit post instead of answering.

Comment: Hmm, that's unfortunate. It isn't throwing an error on my end, but I'm only using intellisense and no real type checking. I think I'll refrain from adding the workaround from the edit since it does use that.

Comment: Where does IntelliSense fail to meet your expectations? What are your desired goals? Please describe your problem in detail. In addition, Pylance is based on Microsoft’s Pyright static type checking tool, leveraging type stubs (.pyi files) and lazy type inferencing to provide a highly-performant development experience.

Comment: `C = type("C", (A, B), {})`. `NewType` is simply the wrong tool here.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the current version of the VS Code syntax highlighter does not support hinting that the output of a function is a subclass of two parent classes.**This is a limitation of the syntax highlighter, and you are not doing anything wrong.**
There are a couple of things you can do to work around this limitation as:

1.You can use a type hint like **type[Union[A, B]]** to hint that the output of the function can be either of the parent classes or a subclass of both.

2.can use a **docstring** to document the fact that the output of the function is a subclass of both parent classes. This will not affect the syntax highlighting, but it will at least tell other developers what to expect.

3.Also, there's **third-party type checker like MyPy** to check the types of your code. **MyPy can detect that the output of the class_factory function is a subclass of both parent classes**

I personally used the third option since it was known to me then, later my professor told me about the other 2 options I stated.

Comment: The first paragraph and the third point aren't quite right. The code in the question isn't using type hinting features correctly and does not pass type checking. Mypy doesn't "detect that the output of the class_factory function is a subclass of both parent classes" - it emits type errors for it. There's currently no way to make point 3 work, since there's no way to communicate intersection types to mypy. Using a union type is a good suggestion though, since at least that way the return type will be compatible with both `A` and `B`.